# how to if else condition in html tag on controller

Tags: html, laravel, if-statement, foreach

hello guys I would like to set my option selected on my controller using foreach in html tag

this is my controller :

```
$category = Subcategory::where('category_code', $request->category_code)->get();
$selected = 'selected';
foreach ($category as $item) {
    $html .= '<option value="'.$city->code.'" '.if($request->subcategory_code==$city->code) { echo $selected; }.' >'.$city->name.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: why not use a blade? give this a read: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#introduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
$category = Subcategory::where('category_code', $request->category_code)->get();
foreach ($category as $item) {
    $html .= '<option value="' . $city->code . '"' . ($request->subcategory_code==$city->code ? ' selected' : '') . '>'.$city->name.'</option>';
}
```